# ORDS ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

During installation, ORDS created a TEST user and granted rights, according to the instructions

[1.3.4.1 ORDS Installer Privileges Script.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/19.2/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html#%20GUID-C613F122-E849-4EDC-8169-04140EDCFB64)

Issued the appropriate rights.
But when trying to enable AUTOREST with (under user TEST):

```
BEGIN

     ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT(p_enabled => TRUE,
                        p_schema => 'MAIN',
                        p_object => 'SOME_TABLE',
                        p_object_type => 'TABLE',
                        p_object_alias => 'some_table',
                        p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);
     commit;
END;
```

I get:

```
[Error] Execution (49:1): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Oracle 11.2.0.4

ORDS latest

APEX 20.02

Comment: If this is for the `TEST` user, why did you specify `p_schema=>'MAIN'`? Also, what user were you logged in as when running the command, and did that user have `execute` permissions on `ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT`?

Comment: I logged in as user MAIN and I can give myself permission through ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT.
But I want to connect to ORDS through user TEST.
At the same time, the objects I need are in the MAIN scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You have to use the ORDS_ADMIN package to enable a schema or object other than your own.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/22.4/orddg/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-8E36C96B-7ACE-46CE-A803-C5C38F0E107A)

To use this package, your user needs the [ORDS Administrator role](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/22.4/ordig/miscellaneous-configuration-options-of-ORDS.html#GUID-F5B4FA7C-E7D6-4182-9787-22909194B136).

So, do this

```
GRANT ORDS_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE TO HR_ADMIN;
```

Then login as TEST and run this

```
BEGIN

     ORDS_ADMIN.ENABLE_OBJECT(p_enabled => TRUE,
                        p_schema => 'MAIN',
                        p_object => 'SOME_TABLE',
                        p_object_type => 'TABLE',
                        p_object_alias => 'some_table',
                        p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);
     commit;
END;
```

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am a product manager on the database team and cover ORDS.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!
Please tell me how to make the user TEST have access to MAIN objects through ORDS?
The matter is that after execution of the command specified by you, objects became available to the MAIN user, not to the TEST.

Comment: if you publish REST APIs on schema MAIN, it's objects will be made available using queries executed as user MAIN. Those APIs will be available to any properly authenticated and authorized requestor. It sounds like you are using database users to authenticate the requests. You don't want to do that. It'd be better to use an OAUTH2 client. Or a Web Gateway or control AUTH via your webserver (tomcat, weblogic, ...)

Comment: In short, in my database, all tables are covered by Date Redaction. The MAIN user is the owner of the main scheme with personal data and part-time SYSDBA. That's why I don't want to use the MAIN schema as it can take the Date Redaction off of itself.))

Comment: The SQL and PL/SQL in the APIs are execute as the user tied to the schema in which they are defined. So if you define an API in SCHEMA X, all the API calls will be executed in the DB as user X. If user X has the data redacted, so will these APIs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will think about another solution.)

Comment: use a view in a schema with the proper security model in the database, and create your REST APIs in that schema, using that view